# Swift compiler hangs! Is it a bug?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

At one point, while I was working on a Swift project, the Xcode got stuck with "Compiling Swift source" message in the status bar. The compilation did not finish no matter how long I waited. I rolled back my recent changes, and soon realized that what confuses the compiler is a very simple enum construct. Below is a Playground example that illustrates the problem.

Create a new Playground and paste this code. Do you see any output?

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

enum FastingType: Int {
    case NoFast=0, Vegetarian, FishAllowed, FastFree, Cheesefare
}

class Fasting
{
    var allowedFood = [
        .NoFast:        ["meat", "fish", "milk", "egg", "cupcake"],
        .Vegetarian:    ["vegetables", "bread", "nuts"],
        .FishAllowed:   ["fish", "vegetables", "bread", "nuts"],
        .FastFree:      ["cupcake", "meat", "fish", "cheese"],
        .Cheesefare:    ["cheese", "cupcake", "milk", "egg"]
    ]

    func getAllowedFood(type: FastingType) -> [String] {
        return allowedFood[type]
    }
}


var fasting = Fasting()
println(fasting.getAllowedFood(.Vegetarian))
println("Hello world")
```

On my machine the busy indicator keeps spinning forever, and there are no messages. I tried this on both Xcode 6.1 (6A1052c) and Xcode 6.2-beta (6C86e).

Does this look like a bug in Swift compiler? Or there is some problem in my code?

**UPDATE:**

Several people noticed that I forgot return type in `getAllowedFood` function. This fix alone, however, does not solve the problem. The compiler still hangs.

A workaround was suggested in comments:

> Swift seems to have trouble interpreting your dictionary. It's usually a good idea to give dictionaries an explicit type to "help out" the compiler.

The following addition "un-freezes" the compiler:

```
var allowedFood: [FastingType: [String]]
```

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: use `FastingType.NoFast` instead of `.NoFast`. `getAllowedFood` need return type

Comment: Never test in a playground. (I know that's what Apple says they are for, but just don't do it.) The compiler would have given you clear error messages if you just did all that in a real app rather than a playground.

Comment: Oh, one more piece of advice. There can be bugs in Swift or Cocoa, sure, but you will not learn to program unless you learn first that when things go wrong, it's _you_ that's doing something wrong.

Comment: matt: About testing in Playground: I wrote above that problem was noticed in Xcode project, and I only created playground to illustrate it

Comment: If I am doing something wrong, the compiler should show an error message, not loop infinitely!

Comment: Matt's advice is pragmatic, but yes, compilation should be essentially deterministic and never loop infinitely, even in a playground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can be considered a compiler bug.  The compiler is having trouble figuring out the type of the key in your dictionary.  The infinite looping behavior can be eliminated by giving the dictionary an explicit type or making sure the first value is fully specified with `FastingType.NoFast`.

Try this:

```
enum FastingType: Int {
    case NoFast=0, Vegetarian, FishAllowed, FastFree, Cheesefare
}

class Fasting
{
    var allowedFood:[FastingType: [String]] = [
        .NoFast:        ["meat", "fish", "milk", "egg", "cupcake"],
        .Vegetarian:    ["vegetables", "bread", "nuts"],
        .FishAllowed:   ["fish", "vegetables", "bread", "nuts"],
        .FastFree:      ["cupcake", "meat", "fish", "cheese"],
        .Cheesefare:    ["cheese", "cupcake", "milk", "egg"]
    ]

    func getAllowedFood(type: FastingType) -> [String] {
        return allowedFood[type]!
    }
}
```

Changes:

1. Gave `allowedFood` the type `[FastingType: [String]]` so that it could interpret your enum values.
2. Gave `getAllowedFood()` a return type.
3. Unwrapped the dictionary lookup because they always return optionals.

Alternatively, you could have `getAllowedFood()` to `return allowedFood[type] ?? []` which would be safer if your dictionary is not exhaustive.

Comment: Or you could use a switch statement in getAllowedFood to avoid the `!`

Comment: Thanks for "fixing" my code. I intended to ask a different question, though: why the original code made the compiler loop infinitely?

Comment: I guess you could definitely call it a bug.  Swift seems to have trouble interpreting your dictionary.  It's usually a good idea to give dictionaries an explicit type to "help out" the compiler.

Comment: Note that just changing `.NoFast` to `FastingType.NoFast` stops the infinite loop behavior because it assumes that all of the other keys must be `FastingType` as well.

Comment: Thanks, vacawama! I mark your answer as Solution :-)